# Is it possible to use a SocketChannel with a BluetoothSocket on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

you can make a SocketChannel from a SocketAddress, but suppose you have a BluetoothSocket. How to make a SocketChannel?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can get a `ReadableByteChannel` and a `WriteableByteChannel` from its input and output streams via the `Channels` class.

Comment: thanks. i didnt know about that. However, a ReadableByteChannel from a stream just calls read on the stream. I was wondering if there's any hope of a bluetooth non-blocking read.